# Confusing with integral. $\int \frac{z^2-1}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1+z^4}}dz$

Tags: integration

$$\displaystyle\int \dfrac{z^2-1}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1+z^4}}dz$$

I tried to make an substitution $\tan x=z^2$ and things got more complicated, and I tried to use $(a-1)(a+1)=a^2-1$ and didnot go no where, so I need hint, thank you in advance.

Comment: I know but sometimes even wolfram cannot solve some integral which requires some clever nonstandard substitutions etc. By the way it is a exercise problem of mine to be ready for exams

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $z>0,$

$$\dfrac{z^2-1}{(1+z^2)\sqrt{1+z^4}}=\dfrac{1-\dfrac1{z^2}}{\left(z+\dfrac1z\right)\sqrt{z^2+\dfrac1{z^2}}}$$

Set $\displaystyle\int\left(1-\dfrac1{z^2}\right)dz=u$ and then $\sqrt{u^2+2}=v$

Comment: With $u=z+1/z$ it's more useful to write $v=\sqrt{u^2-2}$.